# Can't connect to localhost mySQL on XAMP after adding local domain

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, ssl

Using XAMP for local development, I can successfully connect to local mysql database from local apache server.

But I need SSL for development, so I added a local domain (following these [directions](https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/)), which is working correctly. 
But now I can't connect to local mysql database using CodeIgniter, it returns this error:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
 C:\xampp\htdocs\website\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php 203
```

In my.ini, I set bind-address="0.0.0.0" and commented out #skip-networking

I added a user to mysql and try to connect with these credentials on codeigniter:

```
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'testuser',
'password' => 'passwordtest',
'database' => 'database_test',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

I also tried 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.1:3306 as the hostname

Comment: Bro mention your PHP and MySQL version lah

Comment: Setting up ssl for the web server should not have changed anything related to MySQL or how to connect to it. You say it worked before. What did you change?

Comment: can you connect with a terminal ?

Comment: Since my server was running slow, I was searching for solutions, I tried a lot of thing but nothing worked, then I changed host name for the database connection from localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it worked. This change made mysqli work and it made my server a lot faster

Comment: MariaDB 10.1.38, PHP 7.3.2, Xamp 7.3.2
@Joni If I turn off the local domain VirtualHost, then the SQL database works as normal.